# Cron jobs not running in CentOS

Tags: centos, cron

I have a cron job setup in CentOS 5 but it is not triggering.

I have ensured the daemon is running.

This is the command I gave in crontab file:

0 13 * * * /root/test.sh

Comment: What is `/root/test.sh` supposed to do? How do you know that it isn't working?  .. http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a more appropriate location for this question.

Comment: test.sh is a cpu stress script that should trigger only on certain hours of the day. I am running this script on a virtual machine and monitoring the performance stats. When the script runs the cpu utilization on that virtual machine should be 100% and I don't see that. So it is clear that the script is not running.

Comment: You can check `cat /var/log/cron` to see if it's throwing any errors.